# What is the reason of existance of detaching in git

Tags: git, detach

I have read `git` documents but I can't get what is it the intention of detaching branches in git.

Comment: please comment the reason of why you gave me -1, if you think is duplicated or something tell me and then give me -1

Comment: One of the reasons, we can checkout any commit, do small changes and have a test, without creating a new branch or bring changes to any of the existing branches.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you want to make some change but you don't want that them be part of your branch you can detach your branch. From [A Visual Git Reference](https://marklodato.github.io/visual-git-guide/index-en.html?no-svg#detached):

> When HEAD is detached, commits work like normal, except no named
>   branch gets updated. (You can think of this as an anonymous branch.)
>   [image]
>
> Once you check out something else, say master, the commit is
>   (presumably) no longer referenced by anything else, and gets lost.
>   Note that after the command, there is nothing referencing 2eecb.
>   [image]
>   on the other hand, you want to save this state, you can create a new
>   named branch using git checkout -b name.

Comment: It is recommended to expert relevant content from external source instead of posting just a link. But whenever you do such please add an attribution link to original source.

Comment: @taskinoor Thanks.I will consider this